# Example of elliptic curve with CM (complex multiplication) by \sqrt{-7}

Tags: elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Can someone give me an example of elliptic curve with CM by sqrt(-7) with the action.
I've found a list of examples in the following link but not the action.

http://planetmath.org/examplesofellipticcurveswithcomplexmultiplication

Answer (score 8):

I am sure others (magma, etc) can do the same. With sage the following lines will produce the rational functions $\bigl(f(x,y), g(x,y)\bigr)$ representing the multiplication by $(1\pm\sqrt{-7})/2$ on $E$ in the Weierstrass equation given at the link. Once you have that you can get all endomorphisms.

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([1,-1,0,-2,-1])
sage: K.<t> = NumberField(x^2+7)
sage: EK = E.base_extend(K)
sage: psis = EK.isogenies_prime_degree(2)
sage: [psi.codomain().is_isomorphic(EK) for psi in psis]
[True, True, False]
sage: psi = psis[0]
sage: iota = psi.codomain().isomorphism_to(EK)
sage: psi.set_post_isomorphism(iota)
sage: psi.rational_maps()
```

whose $x$-coordinate $f(x,y)$ is
$$\frac{(\sqrt{-7} - 3)\cdot x^2 + (-2\, \sqrt{-7} - 2)}{8\,x + \sqrt{-7} + 5}$$

Comment: The formula for the CM by $(1+\sqrt{-7})/2$ is *much* simpler than the formula for CM by $\sqrt{-7}$, and the former is actually more useful, since it generates the full endomorphism ring, while $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ is only a subring. (So you statement that from $[\sqrt{-7}]$ you can get all endomorphisms is not accurate.)

Comment: Absolutely right. I added the simpler, but I will now delete the earlier.

Comment: Maybe the sage session will render better and highlight if you add four spaces in the beginning of code.

Comment: Just a note (mostly for myself): the desired endomorphism must have degree 2 by Corollary II.1.5(b) in Silverman's "AAEC" book. (That's also why $\left[  \sqrt{-7}  \right]$ has degree 7 and hence is more complicated...).

Answer (score 5):

See J. Silverman, *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*  (Springer GTM), Proposition 2.3.1. Note that since the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ is 1, this is the only example defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ha!! I was in the middle of typing the same reference when your answer appeared. So you win! Hint for OP: The curve has an endomorphism of degree 2 corresponding to $(1+\sqrt{-7})/2$. There's a general formula for degree 2 isogenies $E\to E'$, so one need merely use that formula and make the additional assumption that $j(E)=j(E')$ to find the desired equation.

Comment: Sorry to steal the answer from you!

Comment: thanks for the help. going through the above mentioned book now. do I need to know any kind of programming language to get the exact action (not particularly for \sqrt(-7) but for any CM)?