# Elliptic curve with CM by $(1+\sqrt{-11}) /2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication, elliptic-functions

Can someone explain to me on how to obtain the endomorphism for elliptic curve with CM by $(1+\sqrt{-11}) /2$?

Given the elliptic curve over $F_{p}$ as $y^2=x^3-13824/539 x + 27648/539 \dots$  how do we actually calculate it? Do we still need to use the Weierstrass $\wp$-function or is there any other method to solve this question?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fine question. Please do not vote to close it.

Comment: Related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153730/example-of-elliptic-curve-with-cm-complex-multiplication-by-sqrt-7

Answer (score 6):

The usual method to do this is to use formulas due to Velu. There's an implementation in PARI given at http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/francois.brunault/parigp/velu.gp